# Login Session read database variables

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, session-variables

i'm having issues with my first php project.
a friend helped me out a little bit with this school project and im stuck now.

i would like to read my database values and use them in my session.

this is my database.php config

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
//DB Config
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'KBZ');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
$odb = new PDO('mysql: host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);



//Other Configs
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']))
{
    $userIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
}
else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
    $userIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
{
    $userIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
else
{
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
?>
```

then i have a connection.php file

```
$user = new user($odb); 
class user
{
var $odb;

function __CONSTRUCT($odb)
{
    $this -> odb = $odb;
}
function loggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['ID']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and my login.php

```
<form id="form-login" role="form" action="" method="post">
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['LoginButton'])){
 $DBchkusr = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password LIMIT 1");
        $DBchkusr -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => hash('SHA256', $password)));
        $valid = $DBchkusr -> fetchColumn(0);
        if ($valid)
        {

          $DBGetID = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `ID`, FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = :username LIMIT 1");
          $DBGetID -> execute(array(':username' => $username));

          $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

          $_SESSION['ID'] = $DBGetID -> fetchColumn(0);
        }
```

how can i display the name of the successful signed in user ?
is it possible to store Database informations as a Session variable like this ?

for example:

## Welcome Back `<?php> $_SESSION['Name']?>` !

thanks in advance.

Comment: what has this got to do with phpmyadmin?

Comment: @symcbean arent queries apart from phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use this when a user successfully logs in:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = $name; // $name is received from database
```

Now use this in welcome back:

```
session_start();
echo "welcome back" . $_SESSION["name"];
```

*Edit:*
Use this in if($valid) statament:

```
if ($valid) {
    $stmt = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = :username LIMIT 1");
    if ($stmt->execute(array($username))) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            // remove any of this session variables as you want
            $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
            $_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"];
            $_SESSION["password"] = $row["password"];
            $_SESSION["name"] = $row["name"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $_SESSION["username"] is working, but when i try to display the realname  using $_SESSION["name"](in db i have id,username,password,name) it wont diplay it

Comment: no error, but it seems to be invisible ? something isnt working as expected, just checked the db and everything is correct up there, username and id gets displayed but no name displayed

Comment: weird, if i add this i still get an error, if i remove some code  some other stuff happens. https://gyazo.com/17e1431782f88214a95b93ddbbe7e489

Comment: here's the error code [Image](https://gyazo.com/cb86839f4fb553014bf705b03caa66e0) line 92 is this if ($stmt->execute(array($username))) {

Comment: I am not cool with pdo i usually use mysqli but I expect that tge variable username is not declared so just try      $username = $_POST["username"]  I mean set the received data to it is variables. sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Alright good news. i've got it working.

```
if ($loginCheck)
        {
          $SQLGetID = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `Account` WHERE `username` = :username LIMIT 1");
          $SQLGetID -> execute(array(":username" => $username));
          if ($SQLGetID->execute(array($username))); { //had to add an ; and it worked


            while ($row = $SQLGetID->fetch()) { // THIS IS LINE 92


                $_SESSION["id"] = $row["ID"];
                $_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"];
                $_SESSION["password"] = $row["password"];
                $_SESSION["vorname"] = $row["vorname"];
                $_SESSION["nachname"] = $row["nachname"];
                $_SESSION["email"] = $row["email"];
                $_SESSION["handy"] = $row["handy"];
            }
        }
```

theres now only one more problem i keep getting this error on login, the rest works now with displaying data [Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmADv.png)

Just fixed it.
Solution: $SQLGetID -> execute(array(":username" => $username)); was unnecessary removed that line of code and it works.
[Gif of the working solution](https://gyazo.com/a4d62413491e5b78d0526054e9238286)